# Replacing core forum pages with views throws a warning

Tags: 7, routes, views, nodes

I set up views for `forum/%` paths to replace the core forum pages, and it works fine except I get this error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in forum_menu_local_tasks_alter()
(line 169 of opt/jenkins/blahblah/modules/forum/forum.module).
```

Line 169 is the last line in this code block:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter().
 */
function forum_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  global $user;

  // Add action link to 'node/add/forum' on 'forum' sub-pages.
  if ($root_path == 'forum' || $root_path == 'forum/%') {
    $tid = (isset($router_item['page_arguments'][0]) ? $router_item['page_arguments'][0]->tid : 0);
```

This is failing because `$router_item['page_arguments'][0]` is defined but it's a string, not an object.

So what are my options here?

- I don't want to hack the forum module to change that line
- I don't want to change the path of my views to something besides forum/%
- So I think I need to figure out how to unset `$router_item['page_arguments'][0]` so that that conditional will short circuit? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using a different URL and fixing links to point to that one. Not a real fix to my problem, but whatever.